# Selinux in permissive mode, ssh key based auth and locked account

Tags: centos6, ssh-keys, selinux

I noticed something weird regarding ssh key based login and selinux in ***permissive*** mode.

Let me introduce you the setup:
The server is an updated Centos 6.4 x86_64.

We create user without a password (the user will then be locked):

```
# useradd testuser
# passwd -S testuser
testuser LK 2013-05-03 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.)
```

Then we setup the ssh keys:

```
# install -d -m 700 -o testuser -g testuser /home/testuser/.ssh/
# install -m 600 -o testuser -g testuser /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Let's check the selinux status

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Then let's try to log in as testuser:

```
# ssh testuser@localhost
Last login: Fri May  3 13:26:32 2013 from ::1
$
```

It works !
Now we set Selinux to the permissive mode

```
# setenforce 0
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

And we try to log again:

```
# ssh testuser@localhost
testuser@localhost's password:
```

SSH doesn't accept the key and asks for a password !

**Question**: Is that a bug ?

EDIT: After restorecon -Rv /home, I have

```
$ ls -laZ ~/.ssh/
drwx------. user wheel unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 ./
drwxr-x---. user wheel unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 ../
-rw-------. user wheel system_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0  authorized_keys

$ getsebool -a | grep 'ssh'
allow_ssh_keysign --> off
fenced_can_ssh --> off
ssh_chroot_full_access --> off
ssh_chroot_manage_apache_content --> off
ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs --> off
ssh_sysadm_login --> off
```

EDIT:
Here is the content of /var/log/secure

```
Jun 13 16:30:51 dhcp-240 sshd[13681]: User testuser not allowed because account is locked
Jun 13 16:30:51 dhcp-240 sshd[13682]: input_userauth_request: invalid user testuser
```

Comment: Try restarting the `sshd` daemon to ensure it knows the current Selinux setting which you have changed while it was running.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Neither a full system restart.

Comment: I've tried to duplicate this as you specified without success. Are you sure you have not altered PAM in any way?

Comment: Thanks for testing this.
Then it must be something in my setup...
I asked this question, because I found this weird, and wondered if I should file a bug. I guess not, then.

Comment: Couple questions. Does the /var/log/secure logs or /var/log/messages logs provide any useful clues to the problem? Is the policycoreutils package installed?

Comment: @ZaSter there is nothing in messages, I updated the question with the content of the secure log.
And the policycoreutils rpm is installed.

Comment: However, the /var/log/secure does say that the account is locked, which could be factor.

Comment: Yes, but then why does it work in enforced mode, which should be less permissive !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the problem.
It seems to be indeed a configuration problem.

If the sshd_config contains the directive `UsePAM no` then the ssh daemon doesn't accept the user key and ask for a password.

With `UsePAM yes` the login via keys is working in all cases (SELINUX permissive or enforced, user account locked or not)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this has nothing to do with SELinux and everything to do with putting mode 644 on your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  The ~/.ssh directory itself should have mode 700 and files within that directory should be mode 600.

According to the [OpenSSH FAQ](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14):

> 3.14 - I copied my public key to authorized_keys but public-key authentication still doesn't work.
>
> Typically this is caused by the file permissions on $HOME, $HOME/.ssh
>   or $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys being more permissive than sshd allows
>   by default.
>
> In this case, it can be solved by executing the following on the
>   server.
>
> ```
> $ chmod go-w $HOME $HOME/.ssh
> $ chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
> $ chown `whoami` $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```
>
> If this is not possible for some reason, an alternative is to set
>   StrictModes no in sshd_config, however this is not recommended.

You may also need to do a "restorecon -Rv /root" and "restorecon -Rv /home".  Take a look at the directory ownership and SELinux labels with "ls -lZ".

Comment: I changed the permission for the authorized_keys file.
And in my setup, it still doesn't allow to log in in permissive mode.

Comment: Well, assuming that (ls -laZ ~/) shows user_home_dir_t for the .ssh folder and user_home_t for the files inside, then it won't be a labeling issue.  Which means it might be a boolean issue or policy issue.  You can search the booleans with (getsebool -a | grep 'ssh').

Comment: I edited the question to add the output of ls -laZ.
Restorecon restored the .ssh folder to ssh_home_t and not user_home_dir_t.
Also, I reread my question, and I not sure I made it clear that with SELINUX in enforced mode, the ssh login works !

Comment: I'm wondering why the user's home director (/home/user) is mode 750, and why the group ownership is wheel, instead of user, for ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/*.  And yes, it's odd that flipping SELinux from Enforcing to Permissive affects things in that way.  Maybe try looking at "sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log" with an eye out for ssh errors.